# Android top left button

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I want to make an about button in the top left. I tried:

```
android:layout_gravity:"top|left"
```

but it doesn't work , I searched and all what I found was using `RelativeLayout` and if I use that  I'll have to make all my layout from beginning and it's not that good like the linear layout.

Couldn't post the code here. So this is my code on pastebin

http://pastebin.com/5EjgyB0K

Comment: what layout are you using. show more code.

Comment: this is my full xml Code *in the next answer*

Comment: I've inserted the code in the question ..

Comment: RelativeLayout is very good for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have given `android:layout_gravity="center"` to the Linear Layout so it is going to set gravity of the layout and as `center` and your `About Button` is child of layout its to going to set in `center` and you have given `Margin_top` also.Try to remove gravity amd Margin_top and you can see the result, the button will be top|left of the screen.

Comment: I did, and the button went to the top left , but the title and the next buttons did so .. I want the about left , title centered , and the next is on the right .. this is the code http://pastebin.com/YEB92X6u

Comment: It's ok , I used relative like Niko said .. and its working great .. thank guys